# PayPal Credit Card NVP recurring payment profile getting cancel immediately after creating user's new profile

Tags: php, paypal, credit-card, paypal-nvp

I have integrated NVP method to do recurring payment using Credit Card with PayPal in my site.

After doing payment, new profile of user is creating in merchant's account of PayPal. But immediately second row is getting added in PayPal site that showing Canceled status of profile. And payment not happening properly.

My request to do payment using Credit Card with NVP method is as follows.

```
Array
(
    [METHOD] => CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
    [PROFILESTARTDATE] => 2014-08-20T0:0:0
    [BILLINGPERIOD] => Day
    [BILLINGFREQUENCY] => 5
    [TOTALBILLINGCYCLES] => 8
    [STARTDATE] => 08202014
    [MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS] => 1
    [EMAIL] => dink_templeton@gmail.com
    [INITAMT] => 168.00
    [USER] => charllie_muldoon_biz1_api1.gmail.com
    [PWD] => BXXE478S6LXCU6KZ
    [SIGNATURE] => AooyYNxMo0Q8AUydHyEilzH9UvvoAXpJWgERAqJ.6VwsXjfKorwrUPex
    [VERSION] => 98.0
    [PAYMENTACTION] => Sale
    [IPADDRESS] => 127.0.0.1
    [CREDITCARDTYPE] => MasterCard
    [ACCT] => 5438806788005826
    [EXPDATE] => 022015
    [CVV2] => 456
    [FIRSTNAME] => Danny
    [LASTNAME] => Cause
    [STREET] => 
    [CITY] => 
    [STATE] => 
    [COUNTRYCODE] => 
    [ZIP] => 
    [AMT] => 159.00
    [CURRENCYCODE] => CHF
    [DESC] => Purchasing Ocean Membership
)
```

and response is

```
Array
(
    [PROFILEID] => I-EH0V0LP1TFEY
    [PROFILESTATUS] => PendingProfile
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-08-20T09:31:04Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 4756791a783e
    [ACK] => Success
    [VERSION] => 98.0
    [BUILD] => 12403652
)
```

Can you know the reason why second entry is adding that cancelling the created profile ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope that's not a real credit card number

Comment: Yes Machavity, I am using test credit card in Sandbox mode.

Answer (score 0):

Since your receiver account(charllie_muldoon_biz1_api1.gmail.com) is **an US account therefore you cannot accept the CHF currency  using the direct credit card payments** .and is the reason for the profile cancellation .  **Only the UK and Canadian merchants can accept the CHF currency using the direct credit card payments .**

**However if the recurring profiles are created using the express checkout(Means PayPal account) you are free to accept all the currency accepted by the PayPal .**

You can find the supported currencies for the credit card payments country wise at the below url :

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPWebsitePaymentsPro/